# RGoogleDocs - uploadDoc does not replace doc with same name

Tags: r, google-docs

I am using the **RGoogleDocs** package to upload a string of text to a document.

The following code is a minimal working example.

```
library(RGoogleDocs)
gpasswd = "mypassword"
auth = getGoogleAuth("example@gmail.com", gpasswd)
con = getGoogleDocsConnection(auth)
uploadDoc("test1", con, name = "d")
```

The problem: if I run this code twice **two** files named "d" appear.
In other words, the file is not replaced, even though in the function guide *?uploadDoc* expected behaviour reads as

```
uploadDoc(content, con, name, type = as.character(findType(content)), 
       binary = FALSE, asText = FALSE, folder = NULL, ...)
```

-

```
name     the name of the new document to be created (or the document to be replaced).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Farrel Buchinsky brought this to my attention. It is often best to contact a package's author/maintainer if there is a problem as we don't necessarily follow both R-help and SO.)

Noah is right in saying just deleteDoc() and the uploadDoc().

We can do this in the uploadDoc() also.
I've just added a replace parameter to uploadDoc() (default is TRUE)
and that will (when I solve a possibly related bug)
  a) move the current document, if it exists, to a temporary name
  b) upload the new document to the target name,
  c) delete the temporary document if the upload was successful
     or, if not, move the temporary document back to the original name.

Something is up internally when testing this, but this should be in the next release.

Comment: The new version (0.5-0) is now available on the Omegahat repository in source form (no binaries at this moment).

Comment: A much better solution than what I was trying to get to work using the "edit-media" attribute of a document.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function guide here is a bit misleading. The `uploadDoc` function just creates a new document, and Google doesn't prevent you from having multiple docs named the same thing.

There is a stub in `RGoogleDocs` for `updateDoc()`, but it's been on the horizon for a while (last update of the package was 10/2009). I played for a few minutes, but would take some real digging to get it working.

Not a satisfying answer, but you could always just issue a `deleteDoc()` before re-uploading by the same name.